# Best quote/value of multiple columns using AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am wondering if it is possible to work out the best quote from multiple columns and then use the lowest value.

```
@quote1 = '1000.00'
@quote2 = '2000.00'
@quote3 = '3000.00'
```

so in the email i would like to select the @quote1 and all the quote information surrounding it IE quote, provider, etc

any help would be appricated!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous algorithms to find the lowest of three numbers.  There are no arrays in AMPScript, so you basically have to do it manually.

```
%%[

var @quote1, @quote2, @quote3, @lowestQuote

set @quote1 = '3000.00'
set @quote2 = '1000.00'
set @quote3 = '2000.00'

set @lowestQuote = iif(@quote1 < iif(@quote2 < @quote3, @quote2, @quote3), @quote1, iif(@quote2 < @quote3, @quote2, @quote3))

]%%
<br>quote1: %%=v(@quote1)=%%
<br>quote2: %%=v(@quote2)=%%
<br>quote3: %%=v(@quote3)=%%
<br>lowestQuote: %%=v(@lowestQuote)=%%
```

**Output**

```
quote1: 3000.00 
quote2: 1000.00 
quote3: 2000.00 
lowestQuote: 1000.00
```

You can also use SSJS. There's an example on how to do that [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/24854/5202).

**UPDATE 20150615**

Utilizing the [Add()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#Add) function forces the strings to be evaluated as numbers:

```
%%[

var @quote1, @quote2, @quote3, @lowestQuote

set @quote1 = add('88.73',0)
set @quote2 = add('105.54',0)
set @quote3 = add('106.32',0)

set @lowestQuote = iif(@quote1 < iif(@quote2 < @quote3, @quote2, @quote3), @quote1, iif(@quote2 < @quote3, @quote2, @quote3))

]%%

<br>quote1: %%=v(@quote1)=%%
<br>quote2: %%=v(@quote2)=%%
<br>quote3: %%=v(@quote3)=%%
<br>lowestQuote: %%=v(@lowestQuote)=%%
```

**Output**

```
quote1: 88.73 
quote2: 105.54 
quote3: 106.32 
lowestQuote: 88.73
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for this.  could you explain the lowest quote as i am trying to understand the logic

Comment: Hi Adam, just been testing this and its not pulling the cheapest quote<br>

Comment: Hi Adam, just been testing this and its not pulling the cheapest quote it should pull quote1 - 
quote1: 88.73 
quote2: 105.54 
quote3: 106.32 
lowestQuote: 105.54

Comment: Are you using number or string values?

Comment: string value (text 50)

Comment: you'll have to use a math function to force a numeric comparison.  I updated my answer.